# How to Use "SET DATEFIRST 1" in Entity Framework before getting the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have requirements to get the weekly count in EntityFramework. I get the weekly data but the problem is that in SQL Server week is getting considered from Sun to Sat (Week Starts from Sun and Ends on Sat) but i want the week from Mon to Sun(Week Starts from Mon and Ends on Sun).

I know in SQL server how can do it(using SET DATEFIRST 1 before executing 
 the query), but i don't know how can i do in Entity Framework, so friend
 please help me.

Thanks
Raviranjan

Comment: Here is one technique: http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/12/getting-dayofweek-in-linq-to-entities.html

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for your response, if i tweek in your posted Url it may work but the problem will be when i am doing weekly grouping to get the record count and data is for more than 1 year.